# [SPRING-DATA-NEO4J]Error lucene

Tags: spring, neo4j, lucene, spring-data-neo4j

I need help.
I downloaded the example cineasts from:

http://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-neo4j/tree/master/spring-data-neo4j-examples

And then run whith `jetty:run`

This is code in console:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5890441

When go to `localhot:8080/populate`, in console appears:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/favicon.ico] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

But generates fine:

- data base
- lunece
- tmp-jsp

When  I go to registrate or login, get the error:

```
No element found in org.neo4j.impl.lucene.LuceneIndex$1@6978d57d
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPNz1.png)

Comment: Probably you should "register" first before you can log in?

Comment: There was an issue with this function. I pushed a fix to the repo, can you check that it helped?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling `http://localhost:8080/populate` instead of your localhot:8080/populate ?